# Amazon SQS character encoding problem

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

I am trying to insert characters like ä, á, ó, í, â, etc in message body of Amazon SQS. But these characters get converted to some other characters in SQS (e.g. Ã¤). Is there a way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I think the best way to over-come this problem is to store the message body in AmazonSQS in HTML-ENTITIES format. So before storing the message I encode it in HTML_ENTITIES format using php method [mb_convert_encoding(string $str, string $to_encoding [,mixed $from_encoding])](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

If anyone has a better solution please feel free to add your comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to a character encoding issue in your code. A highly recommended article about this topic is Joel's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

It looks like your characters are being UTF-8 encoded somewhere and the corresponding UTF-8 decode operation is not being performed as you expect.

Comment: I don't think so, because when I echo the message string it looks alright. The characters change only when it goes in AmazonSQS. Thanks

Comment: When you `echo` the data to an HTML page, your *browser* is probably decoding the UTF-8 encoded data and displaying the data properly as you expect. When working with encoded data (as is the norm these days), there are always a lot of layers of translation going on and it usually requires some research to find out what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

try 
utf8_encode

Answer (score 0):

I saw that this was solved at onlinemq but still exist in SQS